# T-SQL Eliminating duplicate rows while ignoring certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I'm struggling to find the proper statements to select non-duplicate entries that are duplicates *only for particular columns*. As an example, in the following table I only care about rows that have unique values in col1, col2, and col3   and the values in col4 and col5 do not matter. This means I would consider row 1 and row 2 to be duplicates and row 4 and row 5 to be duplicates:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 A    2    p    0    2
 A    2    p    1    8
 A    3    r    4    12
 B    0    f    3    1
 B    0    f    6    5
```

And I would want to select only the following:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 A    2    p    0    2
 A    3    r    4    12
 B    0    f    3    1
```

Is there a way to combine multiple DISTINCT statements to achieve this or specify certain columns to ignore when comparing rows for duplicates?

Comment: You need some short of logic to choose what is returned in columns 4 and 5. If you really don't need them at all omitting them from the SELECT DISTINCT Field list will do the job

Comment: I need to keep columns 4 and 5 in my output so unfortunately can't just omit them from the DISTINCT field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose which lines you want to keep, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY col4 DESC) 'RowRank'
      FROM table
     )sub 
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

You can change the `ORDER BY` section to change which row you keep and which you toss.  The `ROW_NUMBER()` function just assigns a number to each row, in this example, you want to preserve each combination of `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, so you `PARTITION BY` them, meaning that numbering will start at 1 for each combination of them.  You can run just the inside query to get the idea.

Alternatively, you could use `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions, ie:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4), MAX(col5)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

The downside here is that the `MAX()` of `col4` and `col5` might come from different rows, so you're not necessarily returning one single row from your original table, but if you don't care which row you return then it doesn't matter.

Comment: I modified your initial solution to just have a nested SELECT:
SELECT 
    *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(col1) AS unique_col1,
               col2, col 3
        FROM table)
ORDER BY unique_col1;

And this seems to work for me. Is this sufficient or will leaving out the PARTITION cause unexpected problems?

Comment: Well if you only want to return col1,col2,col3, you can just use:
`SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2,col3
 FROM table`
The point of using the ROW_NUMBER() was to be able to return full rows based on the 3 values.

Comment: Also, the GROUP BY solution does work; one question-- col 4 and 5 will always be timestamps in increasing order so I actually think it would always return the same row? (The later one?)

Comment: Sub is just an alias for the subquery, sql server requires that.  And yeah, MAX() will always grab the latest date, MIN() the earliest.